# In the board game Risk, if an territory with infinite troops attack a territory with infinite troops, how many troops are they each expected to lose?

Tags: probability, limits, dice

if you don't know the rules of Risk:

The attacker throws 3 dice and the defender throws 2. They compare their strongest dice, and the loser loses a troop. Then they compare their second strongest dice and the loser loses a troop. The defender always wins ties. They do it over and over until until someone runs out of troops.

if they each have infinite troop, how many will they each lose? or what is the ratio of lost troops of one against the other?

Comment: How does this stop if both players start with infinitely many troops?

Comment: it doesn't, and they would both lose infinite troops. But one one them would lose them more quickly, so there is a ratio between the two.

Comment: each one lose infinite troops because the expected number of loses in each battle (aka dice throwing) is not zero for both players, hence in infinite battles the expected number of loses are infinity for each one.

Comment: If the attacker has $a$ troops and the defender has $b$ troops then after $t$ throws where $t\ll \min(a,b)$ we can calculate the expected number of lost troops on each side.  By linearity of expectation, the ratio of lost troops will be the same after many throws as it is for a single throw.  Now... in a single throw of three attacking dice versus two defending dice, how many result in two deaths for attackers?  how many result in one death for each?  how many result in two deaths for defenders?

Comment: After some code or some searching, you should be able to verify that out of the $6^5=7776$ possible die results of five distinct dice, two of which for the defender, $2890$ of the rolls result in two defender deaths, $2275$ result in one death for each, and $2611$ result in two attacker deaths.  The ratio of defender deaths to attacker deaths is then $(2\cdot 2890+2275)::(2275+2\cdot 2611)$, or simplified $895::833$, which is about $15::14$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, that is the answer I was looking for.